# Find real parameter in an inequality

Tags: inequality

Consider the following inequality (on the left side on the equivalence sign).

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\geq a\left(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x+y} \right)\iff (x+y)^{2}-(5axy+2ay^{2})\geq 0$$

Find all real values of $a$, such that this inequality holds for all $x$ and $y$ out of the positive real numbers.

I was able to equivalently manipulate this expression and got to the expression on the right side of the equivalence sign. How do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition
$$\forall x,y>0\quad x^2+(2-5a)xy+(1-2a)y^2\ge0$$
is equivalent to
$$\forall s>0\quad P(s):=s^2+(2-5a)s+(1-2a)\ge0.$$
Let
$$\Delta:=(2-5a)^2-4(1-2a)=a\left(25a-12\right).$$
$P(s)$ is positive for every $s>0$ iff either $\Delta\le0,$ or $\Delta>0$ and $5a-2+\sqrt\Delta\le0,$ i.e. (after some careful but easy calculation) iff $a\le\frac{12}{25}.$

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Taking polar coordinates, this is equivalent to
$$\forall\theta\in(0,\pi/2)\quad a\le\frac{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2}{(5\cos\theta+2\sin\theta)\sin\theta}$$
or, with $t=\tan\theta$:
$$\forall t>0\quad a\le f(t):= \frac{(1+t)^2}{(5+2t)t}.$$
Calculating $f',$ we find that the minimum of $f(t)$ for $t>0$ is attained for $t=5,$ hence the solutions are all the
$$a\le a_\max=f(5)=\frac{12}{25}.$$

Comment: This is incredible, thank you. But is there a way to go without polar coordinates? Thanks so much, this really enlightened me.